# Getting null trying to read an XML column value SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm trying to read from a table a varchar column, but this column is actually Xml, so I'm converting the value to XML and trying to get a value from there.

The problem is that I'm always getting null. This is my code:

```
declare @Greeting xml = (select CAST(sg.Greeting as xml) from AnsService.Ans.SiteGroup sg with (nolock) where sg.SiteGroupNum = 2032)

select 
    sg.AnswerAs,
    (select xmlData.Col.value('.', 'varchar(max)') from @Greeting.nodes('//Section/Paragraph/Run') xmlData(col)) as Greeting
from AnsService.Ans.SiteGroup sg with (nolock)
where sg.SiteGroupNum = 2032
```

The xml value after the conversion is:

```
<Section xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xml:space="preserve>
  <Paragraph>
    <Run>Thank you for calling Intelli-tec Security Services.  This is [OpFirst] speaking, how may I help you?</Run>
  </Paragraph>
</Section>
```

Anyone can help me to identify my problem here, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several flaws:

- [bad habit to kick: NOLOCK everywhere](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)
- If the XML you show us is complete, there's no need for a `APPLY` on `.nodes()`
- Do not use double `//` before "Section". This triggers a deep search and looks for any element `<Section>` anywhere within the XML
- Your XML defines a default namespace. You have to use it or use wildcards
- You should store the XML in the appropriate type. No casts should be needed (like here `select CAST(sg.Greeting as xml`)
- It looks, as if this XML is stored in the same table from which you are reading the rest. There is (probably) no need to read this into a variable first

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Greeting XML=
N'<Section xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xml:space="preserve">
  <Paragraph>
    <Run>Thank you for calling Intelli-tec Security Services.  This is [OpFirst] speaking, how may I help you?</Run>
  </Paragraph>
</Section>';

--declared namespace
SELECT
    @Greeting.value('declare namespace ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation";
                     (/ns1:Section/ns1:Paragraph/ns1:Run/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') Greeting;

--predefined namespace
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation')
SELECT
    @Greeting.value('(/Section/Paragraph/Run/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') Greeting;

--no namespace but wildcards
SELECT
    @Greeting.value('(/*:Section/*:Paragraph/*:Run/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') Greeting;
```

If my magic crystal ball is working correctly, you need something like this

```
select 
    sg.AnswerAs,
    CAST(sg.Greeting AS XML).value('declare namespace ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation";
                                    (/ns1:Section/ns1:Paragraph/ns1:Run/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Greeting
from AnsService.Ans.SiteGroup sg with (nolock)
where sg.SiteGroupNum = 2032
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Shnugo you are the best, your answer is absolutely correct. I really appreciate your help on this. All of your recommendations are right sadly the database is not mine so I have to use it in the way it is implemented. Thank you so much.